# Is it possible to update a restaurant menu in a Google My Business result?

Tags: seo

The Google My Business information is the summary box of information relating to reviews, contact information, etc that (in desktop view) displays on the right hand side of a search result for many businesses.

As a webmaster for a small local business all of the following tasks are my responsibility. I've setup Google Analytics, Webmaster Tools, and update a restaurant's Google Plus page by claiming it and verifying ownership with Google My Business. Now, the restaurant menu is still pointing to urbanspoon.com. There's no feature in the Google My Business settings to update this information. Is there a place I'm not finding for changing this bit of information? If not, are there any optimization tricks I need to know to affect this change? I've already put in a request at urbanspoon to update their menu information. It's been days now, and no update on their end.

### EDIT

I'm referring to the portion you might see in a Google search result, located to the right in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: While I do not know how to manipulate these results, I did see an article online sometime back that illustrated just what you are asking. As an aside, it may take weeks or longer to see a change. Search engines are notoriously slow due to volume and scale.

Comment: Are you talking about "menu cards" as seen here: http://searchengineland.com/now-official-google-adds-restaurant-menus-search-results-185708 or schema.org mark-up??

Comment: @closetnoc I updated the screenshot to show the full view, and circled the menu link I'm trying to update.

Comment: Okay. This comes from schema.org mark-up on your site and is served by the Google Knowledge Graph/Vault and takes quite a while to update- perhaps longer than the SERPs. Here is a MOZ link on the SERP page elements: http://moz.com/blog/mega-serp-a-visual-guide-to-google

Comment: You may want to look at my first link too. It is a menu card and may also be where menu items are coming from- a 3rd party. I will leave room for someone who may have experience with this to answer.

Comment: Thanks, @closetnoc, and I appreciate all the additional info you are sharing with me.

Comment: Anytime!! I am always here short of running out to conduct business. I just wish I knew more. BTW- it has been slow here on the weekends since the holidays.

Comment: This has happened to me a few times. In fact, right now. In the past, it had been scammy sites that try to get you to purchase an account to update your menu. I had been made to call Google. I forget where I got the number but I was connected to an abroad service center. I was on hold for a really long time. But they fixed it! Right now Urbanspoon also took my menu link. But at least it's an accurate menu. Still, I might call.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're using Schemas to mark up your site: https://schema.org/Restaurant

It will help Google to recognize what it is and allow robots to find the right information.